# UITableView scrollIndicator position incorrect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

So I have a `UITableView`. Its dataSource is an `NSArray` of custom objects beeing loaded after a search. When I scroll to bottom, everything works fine, the `scrollIndicator` scrolls to bottom as desired.

Now when I scroll back to top the scrollIndicator stops about 50pixel below my UINavigationbar.

I have no idea why this behaviour occurs only in this `tableViewController`, since my `UITabBarController` consists of 5 `UITableViewcontrollers` each inheriting from the same super class.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:**

Putting the following code in `viewWillAppear:`

```
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets   = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Solved the issue. Although I still don't know why this issue only occurs in one of the five tableViewControllers...

Comment: I did not post any code here as I thought of something like scrollIndicatorInsets could solve the problem. I just was not able to find it myself...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you might have set the `scrollIndicatorInsets`  property of the scroll view wrongly. It might be the same for both bottom and top. Set it so that that you only have the margin for bottom.

i.e
use `UIEdgeInsetMake( <top> , <left>,<bottom>,<right>);` for this. i.e for your case

```
yourScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets   = UIEdgeInsetMake(0, 0,bottomInset,0); //Here bottom inset would be the value you have right now .
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it solved my issue. The weird thing about this issue is that I never change anything on that value and the scrollIndicator is show proerly in all views...
Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As `UITableView's` superclass is `UIScrollView`, its better to set `UIScrollView's` `scrollIndicatorInsets` property to required position.